# iPhone Application Background Timeout

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like my iPhone app to terminate after being in the background for 5 minutes. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. What is the point of doing it?

The best fix (without knowing what you're trying to do) is to store the current timestamp when your app goes into the background and then when it comes back into the foreground see if 5 mins have passed and reset the data or something.

Comment: This makes sense. Just to give some more insight, imagine it is like a banking application: if you navigate away from the app briefly, you want to pick up where you left off when you come right back. But, if you are done for a while, the app will start you at the beginning when you come back (for security and convenience). Think this is still the best option?

Comment: Yeah, I think this is still the best option. :) What you don't want is someone getting hold of my phone a couple of hours later and multi-tasking into my banking app and being able to use all the features, so store a timestamp and when they come back to the app if more than 5 mins has gone by then start them again. :)

Comment: Is there a best way to do this? My whole app lives in 1 navigation controller.

Comment: There are functions in your app delegate which will get called when your application goes into the background and comes back into the foreground. Just store the timestamp in your NSSharedPrefs and compare it when the app is brought into the foreground again. From the app delegate you will (should) be able to access your navigation controller and therefore manipulate data and views.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice to terminate your app explicitly in code. Your app isn't active when in the background in any case, you can only do anything when a piece of your code is running (registered background operations).

If you want your app to stop background operations or to reset itself to a known state if it has been in the background for a specific interval (e.g. 5 minutes) store a timestamp when the app enters the background and react to the timestamp appropriately in any operations and when the app returns to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this

```
LaData=[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:300];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:LaData];

NSDate *ladatadiarrivo=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:300];
while ([ladatadiarrivo timeIntervalSinceNow]>0) {
    if (ExitFlag) return; //To exit when reactivate              

}
//Code to Kill Application
```

Comment: This makes sense. But how do I kill the application and re-start it without them having to tap on the icon again?

Comment: you can kill application with 'exit(0);' but I don't know how to launch application, Really I don't know even if is possible. I'll try to search something about

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Thomas is right.  You should be able to do this easily using User Defaults.  In your delegate you'll just need to do some testing..

```
//See how much time has passed when the app is opened
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
      NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSDate *lastUsed = (NSDate*)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"LAST_USED"];
      NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
      NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastUsed];

      if(interval/60 > 5) { //more than 5 min have passed
           //Force a login
      } else {
           //Continue your session
      }
}
```

And make sure to save your time when the app is closed.

```
//Save the current time when the app is closed
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LAST_USED"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```